# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE users SET AESDataBase.db=? WHERE _id=1

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

При попытке добавления записи в базу данных приложение вылетает.
Код базы данных

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

//import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    static String DB_NAME = "AESDataBase.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private Context myContext;

    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath()+DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput;
        OutputStream myOutput;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
     SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Код основного activity

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class ActivityList extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtListView;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button b3;
    EditText eT;
    ListView listView;
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db_sort;
    long userId=0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        txtListView = findViewById(R.id.txtListView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String outputString = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        txtListView.setText(outputString);
        databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        listView=findViewById(R.id.List);
        eT=findViewById(R.id.eT);

        //создаём БД
       databaseHelper.create_db();
    }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
// открываем подключение
    db_sort = databaseHelper.open();
    //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
    userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);

    // определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
    String[] headers = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
    // создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
    userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME, eT.getText().toString());
            db_sort.update(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userId),  null);
            db_sort.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
        }

    });
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db_sort.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
        }
    });
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                databaseHelper.close();
                userCursor.close();
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
}

        }
```

Лог ошибки

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.chernovik, PID: 22046
                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE users SET AESDataBase.db=? WHERE _id=0
                                                   #################################################################
                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                    (near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE users SET AESDataBase.db=? WHERE _id=0)
                                                   #################################################################
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1008)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:573)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1886)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1834)
                                                       at com.example.chernovik.ActivityList$1.onClick(ActivityList.java:71)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: вот здесь `cv.put(DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME, eT.getText().toString());` вместо DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME должно быть видимо DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME или в какой столбец нужно записать (а не в какую базу данных)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает при исполнении строчки с кодом `db_sort.update...`, а именно sqlite ругается на синтаксис - вы ему сказали изменить данные в поле  `DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME` т.е. строка `AESDataBase.db` (в названии не должно быть запрещённых символов, в данном случае точки). Вы почему то сначала в ContentValues добавляете `DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME` потом говорите sqlite изменить это в таблице в которой нет строки с таким названием `db_sort.update...`. А потом добавить ещё одну запись `db_sort.insert...` но с данными из того же `ContentValues`. Всё зависит от задачи которую вы перед собой ставите.